# Upload report to telerik report-server api with powershell

Tags: powershell, rest, telerik

Trying to upload a report to the Telerik reporting server with PowerShell. I can get/post to other endpoints just fine.

I cant quite see what i am doing wrong. Appreciate any feedback!

```
            $headers = @{
               "Accept"="application/json"; 
               "Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
               "Authorization"="bearer 4X8k++++" }

            $httpfile = @{
                Name="$rptName";
                FileName="$rptFileName";
                MediaType="application/x-zip-compressed";
                Buffer="$( Get-Content "$rptFullname" -AsByteStream )";
            } 

            $rptbody = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name="$rptName";
                Description="$rptDesciption";
                CategoryId="$catagoryId"; 
                ReportFile = $httpfile
            } | ConvertTo-Json

            Write-Debug " ----------rptBody"
            $rptBody | Write-Debug 
            Write-Debug " ----------"

            irm "$($base_uri)/api/reportserver/v2/reports" -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $rptBody
```

Inspecting the rptBody

```
 {
  "Name": "rpt1",
  "Description": "uploaded on 08.Aug.23",
  "CategoryId": "04044ss3f4",
  "ReportFile": {
    "Name": "rpt1",
    "FileName": "rpt1.trdp",
    "MediaType": "application/x-zip-compressed",
    "Buffer": "80 75 3 4 2 ++++" } }
```

Error

{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"model.Name":["The Name field is required."],"model.CategoryId":["The CategoryId field is required."],"model.ReportFile":["The ReportFile field is required."]}}

telerik report-server api ref
https://docs.telerik.com/report-server/implementer-guide/apis/rest-api/v2/post-api-reportserver-v2-reports

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working, had to change the bytestream and added json content type. Ill leave it up if anyone needs a way to migrate telerik reports. We are going to make a choco package to update servers.

```
    $headers = @{
           "Accept"="application/json"; 
           "Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
           "Authorization"="bearer 4X8k++++" }

        $httpfile = @{
            Name="$rptName";
            FileName="$rptFileName";
            MediaType="application/x-zip-compressed";
            Buffer="$( [convert]::ToBase64String( [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes( "$rptFullName" ) ) )";
        } 

        $rptbody = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name="$rptName";
            Description="$rptDesciption";
            CategoryId="$catagoryId"; 
            ReportFile = $httpfile
        } | ConvertTo-Json

        irm "$($base_uri)/api/reportserver/v2/reports" -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $rptBody -ContentType "application/json"
```